Is a spin connection with torsion possible whereas the affine connection is only Levi-Civita (torsion-free) in Supergravity?
In the paper "Simple Supergravity" from G. Dall'Agata & M. Zagermann (arXiv:2212.10044v2 15 Feb. 2023) on page 8 when it comes to the antisymmetric part of the covariant derivative of the 3/2 spin field $\psi_\rho$ (formula 25) the authors say that the antisymmetric derivative only contains the spin connection since the antisymmetric part of the Christoffel symbols is zero:
$$\nabla_{[\nu}\psi_{\rho]} = \partial_{[\nu}\psi_{\rho]}+\frac{1}{4}\omega^{ab}_{[\nu} \gamma_{ab}\psi_{\rho]} - \Gamma^\rho_{[\nu\rho]}\psi_\rho =\partial_{[\nu}\psi_{\rho]}+\frac{1}{4}\omega^{ab}_{[\nu} \gamma_{ab}\psi_{\rho]}$$
($\gamma_{ab}  = \gamma_{[a}\gamma_{b]}$ with $\gamma$ being gamma-matrices (Dirac)). In particular in a footnote the paper's authors say:

"It is important here, that $\Gamma$ denote the torsion-free Levi-Civita connection. As we will see later, it is useful to include a torsion piece bilinear in the gravitini in the spin connection (but not in the connection $\Gamma$, which should stay torsion-free). The connections defined by $\Gamma$ and $\omega$ are then no longer equivalent connections."

However, there is also the Vielbein postulate which actually relates the spin connection and the affine connection:
$$\partial_\mu e^a_\nu - \Gamma_{\mu\, \nu}^\sigma e^a_\sigma -\omega_{\mu\, b}^a e^b_\nu = 0$$
where $e$ are tetrades. Would it mean that the Vielbein postulate is valid for a torsion-less $\Gamma$ and a torsion-containing spin connection $\omega$ ? Or, would it be broken ? Assuming that the second possibility occurs, would a broken Vielbein postulate not pose problems in the whole formalism ?

" Would it mean that the Vielbein postulate is valid for a torsion-less Γ and a torsion-containing spin connection ? Correct: suitably antisymmetrized, Γ drops out, and   consists of a torsionless piece  of antisymmetrized tetrad derivatives and the "contortion", linear in the torsion, so bilinear in the gravitini. Cf the classic Consistent Supergravity by Deser and Zumino, a must.

@Comas Zachos Could you elaborate at bit more ? Actually I can't access the paper from Deser & Zumino.

Eqn 18. The printed version is better.

The basic idea is to start with plain, torsion-free gravity, and correct it by coupling gravitini to it, which leave the  Γ s alone, but correct the spin connections by torsion, a gravitini bilinear.

@Cosmas Zachos Thank you very much !
